# CSRF verification failed in Django project update, and RequestContext solution not working

Tags: django, view, csrf, verification

I have a Django project in which trying to 'update' (clicking on the button) causes the following error:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

I have viewed various questions and answers that suggest that adding RequestContext is the solution, but I have tried something to that effect tailored to my code, and still am unable to get it working.

Original code **views.py** is below

```
#USERS (register) view.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages #this allows us flash messages for testing
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .forms import UserUpdateForm
from .forms import ProfileUpdateForm

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #this UserRegisterForm is created in forms.py and inherits from UserCreationForm (the ready made form)
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) #create a form that has the data that was in request.POST
        if form.is_valid(): #is the form valid (do you have a username like this already, passwords match?
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}, you can now login.')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form =UserRegisterForm() #if the form input is invalid, render the empty form again


    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})


@login_required #this is a decorator (adds functionality to an existing function)
def profile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'Your Account has been directed')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:   
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)


    context={
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }

    return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
```

**As mentioned I also tried:**

```
return render(request,'users/profile.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**I also tried adding the below to imports**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render,redirect
```

**Note**: I do not wish to try the 'remove middleware' alternative.

The **profile.html** file code is below and I have included the CSRF token correctly, as far as I know:

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Information</legend>
            {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update....</button>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Finally, for context, here is **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm): #form that inherits from the usercreationform
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        #when this form validates it creates a new user
        #type the fields to be shown on your form, in that order.
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']   

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Profile
        fields=['image']
```

**Question:** What is causing the error and what do I need to add/change in the code as it stands?

I also came across an answer on StackOverflow which said this "The problem is you are not returning the result. Remember that the view is a function. You need to return render_to_response(...) not just call it (which is also why by removing CSRF you got the didn't return an HttpResponse error)" ....can someone explain this in my context? I don't understand what it means or how to implement it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should work, however I noticed you seem to be missing a quote at the end here

> ```
>  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
> ```

Comment: Thank God for people with the ability to spot details like that ...I'd have never seen it, and as usual the server didn't throw up any errors so couldn't point me in the right direction either! Thank you!